# How to get a numerical value from text field

Tags: ios, textfield

I'm building a mini quiz app, where you have to insert the final answer of a question, and it must be numerical value , I have changed the keyboard to decimal keyboard.

but I'm trying to build a code to check if the value of the text field is the same like the correct answer then run a specific code, but it doesn't work.

```
-(IBAction)submitAnswer:(id)sender{


if (answerText.tag==correctNumber) {
    [self correctAnswer];
}
else{

    [self wrongAnswer];

}
```

Note: correctNumber is a Double

Comment: do you want that user can enter only numeric value in textfield not any string or character??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get a string from the uitextfield

```
NSString *myNumberString = myTextField.text;
```

Convert to a value

```
double myValue = [myNumberString doubleValue];
```

Do your comparison.